# Deployment of a Javafx Application on Wildfly 11.0.0

Tags: javafx, wildfly

I'm currently working with a Wildfly Application Server. I have developed a functioning Javafx Application with jpro. It works locally, but i want to deploy it on the Wildlfy Server.

I have already made a release with mvn jpro:release. Then I used the html code of the locally running test as index.html for Wildfly I also added a WEB-INF folder with a jboss-web.xml. I archived this and deployed it as a .war to Widlfy. Right now, it displays the application but i cannot interact with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><style>body {transition: opacity ease-in 0.2s; } 
body[unresolved] {opacity: 0; display: block; overflow: hidden; position: relative; } 
</style>
    <title>GUI with JPRO</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

    <link href="http://localhost:8080/jpro/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jpro%20Application%20%20default-Dateien/jpro.css">
<script src="jpro%20Application%20%20default-Dateien/jpro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <jpro-app href="localhost:8080/app/default" fullscreen="true">
```

I have kept the most Bottom part out since it is way too much to display here!
If you need to see that feel free to ask.

Since i can see the Application but cannot interact with it, I guess that this is a problem of Wildfly's interaction with JPRO or I use wrong HTML code.

A few side questions.
If I can't deploy it on Wildfly Properly is there anyway to run jpro side-by-side?
I also have an Apache Server, is there any possibility for that to work and if yes, how?

Sorry if this is a bit confusing. I'm kinda in a hurry right now.

Best Regards,
Mika Mohn

Answer (score 0):

[JPro](https://www.jpro.one/) must run as a separate process on your server.
JPro cannot run inside an Application Server.
But you can add JPro to your existing website, even so, it's not running at the same process.

In your project, you can create an application, which you can execute on your server, with the command `gradle jproRelease` or `mvn jpro:release` depending on your build tool.
This will create a zip which contains your application.
Just copy it to your server and execute the start script of the zip file.

Make sure to prepare Linux for JPro based on the documentation: https://www.jpro.one/?page=docs/current/2.7/PREPARING_LINUX_FOR_JPRO